# display image on different php page

Tags: php

i am creating a php image gallery, after a long search i found a good php image gallery code on google. when i click on thumbnail of a image it send to orignal image location, but instead of orignal image i want to send user to different page where the same image display!

here is the code!

```
<?php   # SETTINGS


        $max_width = 200;
        $max_height = 200;
        $per_page = 9;

        $page = $_GET['page'];

        $has_previous = false;
        $has_next = false;

        function getPictures() {
            global $page, $per_page, $has_previous, $has_next;
            if ( $handle = opendir(".") ) {
                $lightbox = rand();
                echo '<ul id="pictures">';

                $count = 0;
                $skip = $page * $per_page;

                if ( $skip != 0 )
                    $has_previous = true;

                while ( $count < $skip && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                    if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' )
                        $count++;
                        }

                $count = 0;
                while ( $count < $per_page && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                    if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
                        if ( ! is_dir('thumbs') ) {
                            mkdir('thumbs');
                        }
                        if ( ! file_exists('thumbs/'.$file) ) {
                            makeThumb( $file, $type );
                        }

                        echo '<li><a href="'.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']">';

                        echo '<img src="thumbs/'.$file.'" alt="" />';

                        echo '<div class="fb">view</div></a></li>';


                        $count++;

                    }

                }

                echo '</ul>';

                while ( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
                    if ( !is_dir($file) && ($type = getPictureType($file)) != '' ) {
                        $has_next = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function getPictureType($file) {
            $split = explode('.', $file); 
            $ext = $split[count($split) - 1];
            if ( preg_match('/jpg|jpeg/i', $ext) ) {
                return 'jpg';
            } else if ( preg_match('/png/i', $ext) ) {
                return 'png';
            } else if ( preg_match('/gif/i', $ext) ) {
                return 'gif';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }

        function makeThumb( $file, $type ) {
            global $max_width, $max_height;
            if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            }
            if ( ($oldW = imagesx($src)) < ($oldH = imagesy($src)) ) {
                $newW = 220;
                $newH = $max_height;
            } else {
                $newW = $max_width;
                $newH = 200;
            }
            $new = imagecreatetruecolor($newW, $newH);
            imagecopyresampled($new, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newW, $newH, $oldW, $oldH);
            if ( $type == 'jpg' ) {
                imagejpeg($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
            } else if ( $type == 'png' ) {
                imagepng($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
            } else if ( $type == 'gif' ) {
                imagegif($new, 'thumbs/'.$file);
            }
            imagedestroy($new);
            imagedestroy($src);
        }
    ?>
```

sorry, my english is not good, hopefully you understand my question!

Comment: If you simply want to redirect the user to the fullscreen image instead of showing it through lightbox, simply remove the `rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']"` part from the line starting with `<li><a href="'.$file.'`. Basically you would need to pass the $file variable to another web page to know the name of the source image file that should be displayed.

Comment: yeah i did this but it simply shows the image!

Comment: See my above comment, you need to pass the $file variable i.e. as `echo '<li><a href="imagehandler.php?i='.$file.'">';` and retrieve the image info through `$file= $_GET['i'];`

Comment: i want user redirect to other page where it display the thumnail image

Comment: it only output image name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code contains a rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.'] in the image link. It is expecting to use Lightbox in the browser to display the image. Lightbox is a JavaScript library (there are lots of clones, too) that displays the image over the existing page and grays out the background. It is pretty nice. You might want to investigate using Lightbox to display the image.

Otherwise, you will need to modify the line:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.$file.'" rel="lightbox['.$lightbox.']">';
```

so that the href point to the page you want with the $file as an GET value in the URL. If you do, you should take out the rel= since you won't be using it. It won't hurt anything but it is just clutter if you don't use Lightbox. For example something like:

```
echo '<li><a href="display.php?image='.$file.'">';
```

where display.php is a page to display the image.

Comment: but how to output image in display.php ?